# Finding the volume of a solid enclosed by two cylinders and planes

Tags: calculus

Consider the solid E1 that is enclosed by the planes z = 0 and z = 5 and by the cylinders X^2 + y^2 = 9 and x^2 + y^2 = 16. Find the volume of E1. I have no idea how to find the volume using two cylinders and it's frying my brain.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of doing it:

1. Using formulas;
2. Integrating.

Let's use the formula that gives us the volume of a cylinder:  $π (radius)^2 height$. We are just gonna subtract the tinner from the bigger: $π(4)^2 5  -  π(3)^25   =  35π$

Now let's integrate!:

$$\iiint{E1} \, dV = Vol(E1)$$

In order to have an easier integral, we should use cylindrical coordinates: $ (x,y,z)$ will "become" $(\vartheta,radius,z)$. Therefore, (not forgetting the distortion):

$$ \int_0^5 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_3^4 (radius)drd\vartheta dz = Vol(E1)$$

Using Fubini's theorem:

$$ \int_0^5dz \int_0^{2\pi} d\vartheta \int_3^4 (radius)dr = Vol(E1)$$

And finally:

$$Vol(E1) = 35 \pi $$

For solving such problems I have set a couple of steps that I encourage you following:

- Draw the region,
- Choose the coordinate system that fits better for the ocasion,
- Set the limits of the variables,
- And then integrate.

It is important to explane why I chose those limits in respect to $r, \vartheta ,z$. The last one is the easiest: the region is confined within the two planes, $z=0, z=5$; about the others: due to the symmetry of $E1$, you are going to rotate $2\pi$ radians a segment of line the starts at 3 (the radius of the tinner cylinder) and ends at 4 (the radius of the bigger one).